# How to use Maple to solve equation normalization coefficient

Tags: maple

I want to ask for the normalization coefficient of the solution **f(x)**.

The implementation method in **Mathematica** is as follows:

```
f[x] := Sin[(n Pi x)/(2 a)];
norm = FullSimplify[1/Integrate[Abs[f[x]]^2, {x, 0, a}], n \[Element] Integers]
```

The final results are as follows:
**2/a**

I want to implement the same function in **Maple**, and have tried the following：

```
assume(n::posint);
psi := x -> sin(1/2*n*pi*x/a);
c := 1/int(abs(psi(x))^2, x = 0 .. a);
simplify(solve(c = 1, a));
```

**Is there a good way to deal with it if it is implemented with Maple?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
restart;

kernelopts(version);

   Maple 2022.0, X86 64 LINUX, Mar 8 2022, Build ID 1599809

assume(n::posint);
f := abs(sin(1/2*n*Pi*x/a))^2:

simplify(combine(1/int(convert(f,Heaviside,x),
                       x=0..a)));

        2
        -
        a

simplify(combine(1/int(f,x=0..a)))
   assuming a::real;

        2
        -
        a
```

Comment: This is a good result. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I've submitted two bug reports: 1) that `int` needs conversion of the `abs` to `Heaviside` for this example, and 2) that `simplify` needs the preliminary call to `combine` to do best (with this example's successfully computed symbolic antiderivative) under the assumption.

Comment: Assuming that `a::real` is a better way to imply that `x` is purely real-valued -- which is what allows the integral to succeed. (I forgot that converting `abs` to `Heaviside` wrt `x` brings that implication.) I've added the better way to the Answer.